# "open with list" disappeared after 16.10 upgrade

Tags: menu, 16.10

after the I upgraded ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10, when I do right click on a file, the open with list no longer appears, it only shows a button that says "Open with other Application". How can I restore the open with list with the associated programs? Thank you

Comment: I am not sure but I think it is because of the upgrade from 3.18 to 3.20 gnomeshell. They use the open with differently, did anything else change during the upgrade process, like anything missing in the settings panel. like appearance.

Comment: As mentioned above there is no 'Open With' list. 'Open with'  is confined to the set default per mimetype, Open with other Application is the new way to access other apps. This is the 'new & improved' nautilus...

Comment: @RichardW.Seitz, no I still have the appearence under settings

Comment: @doug this is just bad... do we have any alternatives? other than change unity?

Comment: You could try some other file managers or just go back to 16.04 which was going to use 3.18 but due to issues we got them to revert back to 3.14 which works just fine. If you're on 16.10 then you're basically committing to going to 17.04/17.10/18.04. I'd just stick with 16.04 as 18.04 may Not be what many current ubuntu users want in a Linux desktop..., better to see it before having to use it.

Comment: I've filed a bug, as this is a usability regression. Please add yourself if you are affected: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1647217

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite sure *Open with Other Applications* is the new *Open with List*. Whenever I use it , it gives a list of all usable applications on my system. The application list is segmented into recommended and other applications, and works similar to Windows' *Open with...* dialog box, if you're familiar with that.

EDIT SINCE I CAN'T COMMENT YET: I still got an *Open With* RMB menu that seems to do what you wanted.

Comment: I had the same thing happen to me originally, I also lost my Ethernet connection during the process, I had to do a fresh install to solve it after I backed up the system.

Comment: I also lost some option in the settings panel as well. like appearance. I have not upgraded my server yet for that exact reason.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my question is, can I have a list with a dropdown menu(of recommended apps), on the right click menu like I used to have? I just really dont like the idea that I have to click on button, for a popup to appear in order to open a file with another app, other than the default one.